# Indico API Wrapper For Java Returning Key Not Found

Tags: rest, indico

I'm attempting to use indico's sentiment analysis api, I've debugged and inspected the "indico" object, and confirmed the correct api key is stored within it. I am also able to make calls to the API using curl from terminal, so I don't believe its my network settings (unless its something java specific?).

The code:

```
    public double querySentiment(String qsent) throws UnsupportedOperationException, IOException, IndicoException{
    double response = 0;

    indico = new Indico(apikey);

    IndicoResult single = indico.sentiment.predict(qsent);
    log.inf("QUERY SEND SUCCESSFUL");

    response = single.getSentiment();
    log.inf("QUERY RECEIVE SUCCESSFUL");
    return response;
}
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: API key not found. To use our API, sign up for a free account and api key at http://indico.io/register.
```

Comment: Getting same error. Any updates ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong code snippet is given on indico API site. You have to pass key in params as well while making an indico object. Below code will work.

HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();

params.add("api_key",apikey);

indico = new Indico(apikey,params);